# Is the blender 3d print thin faces warning possible to figure out here?

Tags: modeling

I have seen many videos and threads about thin faces but still cannot figure this out. I am trying to add a pattern I created to an object but am getting a lot of thin faces warnings. It doesn't make sense though because a bunch of the same exact faces in the pattern are not highlighted as thin faces while many other duplicates are highlighted. I have the size and thickness limit set to the specs I need. Any advice on how to fix this would be hugely helpful. Thank you!

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: can you be more specific? Happy to clarify.

Comment: I created a pattern with many diamond shaped faces that I duplicated a few times to create a larger pattern. Then I ran a check with 3d print tool box and some of the faces came up as too thin while other duplicates were not too thin so I don't understand how the thin face warning function works

Comment: It's already been suggested that you update to the latest Blender version (3.3.2) and possibly file a bug report in your previous question here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278963/is-there-an-additional-bug-with-blender-detecting-thin-faces-for-3d-printing-pre.